# LinqToObject query Unable to cast object of type

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

Why is this query not working

```
Private mapOverlays As New List(Of GMapOverlay)

Dim mapOverlay = mapOverlays.Where(Function(x) x.Id = overlay.Name).Distinct()
DirectCast(mapOverlay,GMapOverlay).IsVisibile = False
```

I am getting the error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'd__7a`1[GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay]' to type
>   'GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because mapOverlay is an enumerable of mapOverlays, not just one mapOverlay.

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
Dim mapOverlay = mapOverlays.Where(Function(x) x.Id = overlay.Name).Single()
mapOverlay.IsVisibile = False
```

If you move your mouse over mapOverlay, you'll see that the type that's being returned is effectively GMapOverlay and not IEnumerable(of GMapOverlay), because Single returns only one element. Distinct on the other hand can return more than one element, it just filters out duplicate values.